# Jensen-Shannon divergence for finite samples

Tags: entropy, distance, information-theory, binning, finite-population

I have two *finite* samples $s_1$ and $s_2$ and two distributions $p_1(s_1)$ and $p_2(s_2)$ that are associated to these samples. I'm essentially interested to measure the distance or similarity between these two distributions. I'm currently using the Jensen-Shannon (JS) distance, which involves in calculating the entropies of the two distributions separately and jointly. 
I need to bin the data for calculating the basic entropy functions and it looks like the resulted JS distance is also a function of the data binning strategy that I use. It sounds quite arbitrary and I don't know how much I can trust the results. 
Is there any way around this? How can I measure the distance between $p_1(s_1)$ and $p_2(s_2)$ in a more rigorous way that needs no data binning or any other sort of arbitrariness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data are taken from a setting where it is useful or realistic to consider that your measurements are "noisy", it may be useful to pick a prior noise model for your data which means that both your distributions have support over the same space.

A simple approach would be to consider that your distributions are Gaussian mixtures with means at the observed data points and a single common variance.  This "smoothing" gives your distribution support on the whole real line, for 1-dimensional data.  It then remains to calculate Kullback-Leibler divergences between the two Gaussian mixtures: there is no closed form solution for this, but you can compute it numerically using the approaches in Hershey and Olsen ([1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.148.2502&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), e.g. by Monte Carlo sampling.  For higher-dimensional data you could use multivariate Gaussian mixtures (with full rank covariance matrices, for the reason given by Matus Telgarsky in the MathOverflow discussion [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72668/how-to-compute-kl-divergence-when-pmf-contains-0s))

Of course this has not removed all arbitrariness - we still have the common prior variance (and the choice of noise model).  But it should be easy to study numerically the behaviour of the Jensen-Shannon divergence as you vary the single parameter of the noise model.